# Isolated Storage in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I am building a Windows Phone app in Visual Stdio 2013 that should run on all versions of windows phone(7,7.5,8,8.1,...).

I need to store around 20mb of data from website that needs to be updated as soon as the change is made in the website.
I am using Isolated Storage for storing offline data.Will IsolatedStorage be able to store 20mb of data ?

Or else what should I use to store offline data?

thanks in advance..

Comment: As WP8.1 is yet to be released, I cannot say about the scope of it. But as far as WP7,8 is concerned, you will be able to store 20MB of data in isolated storage.

Comment: Sqlite is better option to save such kind of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your data through sqlite file which is very easy to implement because you have to store offline data and you can't store the data in IsolatedStorage because once user have download the App and then he may be able to store in Isolated Storage not before.
So you can do one thing first make a sqlite file in which you store your data and then parse the sqlite file in code and store it in Isolated Storage so User will not require Internet.
I have done this before in which i have to download large data from my server and then store it in Isolated Storage in which it usses Internet and also takes time.

Comment: Hi,I need the data to be stored in a structured way ,so I will be using sqlite. So basically,I will be fetching data from the website and storing in sqlite file and extracting the data in the code.But why  do I need to store in Isolated Storage,if I am storing in the sqlite file? I have read on msdn site that 'warning if the sqlite-net-wp8 does not use the same version of SQLite for windows phone you will not be able to open the app'. I need the app to run on all versions of windows phone(7,7.5,8). Should I use Sqlite or else what should I use to store data in structured form? thanks in advnce

Comment: Your first answer is you need to store in Isolated Storage because the time taken in parsing and displaying or accessing that data is lower then in Sqlite file and you can't update the sqlite file which is attached in the bundle you can update your Isolated Storage Data. And your 2nd answer it will run on all versions the thing written there is if you are using sqlite-net version 3.8.0 then there should be same versions in all .

Answer (score 1):

MSDN Says

> Windows Phone apps are not restricted to a particular quota. They
>   should make careful use of storage based on their app scenario
>   requirements.

For more information [see this MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769544%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)